# A question of Integration by parts

Tags: calculus

Consider $\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)dx$. Then the integration by parts gives
$$
\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)dx = \left[ f(x)g(x) \right]_{a}^b - \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx.$$
In the case that $f(a), g(a), f(b), g(b)$ are not defined, can I replace the term $[f(x)g(x)]_a^b$ as $$ [f(x) g(x)]_a^b = \lim_{x \to b} f(x)g(x) - \lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) ? $$
Or is there any condition to justify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the four values you name are not defined "prima vista" the integral in question has to be considered as an improper integral to begin with. In this case
$$\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)\ dx:=\lim_{\epsilon\to0+,\ \epsilon'\to0+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon'} f'(x)g(x)\ dx$$
by definition. Now apply partial integration to the integral $\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon'} f'(x)g(x)\ dx$ and then proceed to the limit, if it exists.